# flow control with jQuery and ajax: Identify which response belongs to which call

Tags: jquery, ajax, control-flow

I want to identify which response belongs to which (async) call. In my client web application I have a list of items. Every time the user navigates to an item the application makes an ajax-call to check if the item is up to date. If the user navigates very fast there are several calls (with the same callback-function) waiting for a response. Is there a way in jQuery to identify which response belongs to which call? Or do I have to implement it myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just found a plugin which seems to solve my problem:

http://docs.jquery.com/AjaxQueue (but there is no download-link today)

I found this way to identify which response belongs to which call:

```
        var xhr = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'service.php',
            dataType: 'json',                
            data: data,
            async: true,
            timeout: 1000,
            success: function(xhr)
            {
                alert('success with callID: ' + xhr.callID);
            },
            error: function(xhr)
            {
                alert('error with callID: ' + xhr.callID);
            },
            complete: function(xhr)
            {
                alert('completed callID: ' + xhr.callID);
            }
        });
        xhr.callID = ++seqNo;
        xhr.itemID = ID;
```

With this information it should be possible to build my own queue.

Answer (score 0):

While calling the $.ajax, specify callback method and callbackData. Specify the itemId as callbackData. When the callback is executed, you will get the itemId back so that you can use this ItemId to update the data related to that particular item

Comment: so I have to do it myself and have to think of all problems with flow control... In the scope of ajax-responses my itemId is not unique. If the user navigates up and down and up again there are several calls for the same itemId, means I have to implement a counter that makes every call unique (like the flow control in TCP)... and maybe there are further problems

Comment: Next problem is: There might be an error ('timeout', 'parseerror', etc.). So how can I identify to which call the error belongs to decide if i should ignore it or try again?

Comment: I don't understand... the error-callback gives me no information to which call it belongs to. I have several parallel calls, I am only interested to get the response of the last call. If I get an error I have to know if it belongs to the last call to decide if I should try again.